# How do I set up two off-camera flashes with Yongnuo RF-603II triggers?

Tags: off-camera-flash, hotshoe-flash, canon-5d-mark-ii, canon-6d, yongnuo

I’m new to this group. Can anyone please tell me the steps for setting up Yongnuo RF-603CII triggers with a Canon Speedlite 430EX, Yongnuo YN-560II, and a Canon 5D Mark II / Canon 6D?

I just want to fire both flashes off-camera at the same time.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping answers. I have three of the 603 and will try it out later on. This site is fantastic, again thanks a lot folks:) Per Oslo Norway

Answer (score 2):

If you only have a single RF-603II, you cannot do this with those flashes.  You will need at least two RF-603II triggers, and preferably three.  The 430EX does not have any "dumb" optical slave modes, and the Canon "wireless" (near-infrared, wireless eTTL) does not work with Yongnuo's S1 and S2 optical slave modes (for that you need Yongnuo's Sc slave mode, which you'll find with their flashes with "EX" in the name, and a Canon wireless eTTL master unit, since the 5D/6D bodies don't have a pop-up flash).  The RF-603II's radio triggering is incompatible with Canon's wireless master/slave modes.

In addition, you will not have command capability from the camera menus, no eTTL, no groups, and you cannot use shutter speeds faster than 1/200s (i.e., no high-speed sync). If you wanted remote power control, you should have gotten YN-560IIIs and a YN-560-TX or YN-560IV as on-camera master.  If you wanted everything, you should have gotten a YN-568EX not a YN-560II, and the YN-622C triggers not the RF-603s.

The steps are:

1. Make sure all the batteries in everything are in good health and freshly charged. Low or bad batteries can cause either the camera, flashes, or triggers not to work properly, and it can become hard to determine what caused an issue.
2. Set all the triggers to use the same channel.  With the RF-603IIs, this is done with DIP switches in the battery compartment.
3. Place one RF-603II on the camera to act as the transmitter. Make sure it is in either Tx or TRx mode.
4. Attach another RF-603II to the 430EX, make sure it is in TRx mode.
5. Turn on the 430EX, and make sure that it is OUT of wireless slave mode (this would tell it to ignore the signals from the radio trigger and instead to "listen" to the red optical slave receiving panel) and that it is in M mode.
6. Set up the YN-560II as a slave.

   a. If you have a third RF-603II, attach it to the foot of the YN-560II, and make sure it is in TRx mode. Make sure the YN-560II is in M mode and out of S1/S2 (same deal as with the 430EX--putting it in an optical slave mode tells it to ignore the foot and thereby the radio trigger).

   b. If you don't have a third RF-603II, turn on the YN-560II and place it in S1 mode.  Make sure that the red slave panel on the front of the 560II is facing towards the 430EX's light output. Rotate the head if you have to.
7. Adjust the power levels on the flashes directly using their LCD panels.
8. Take a shot or use the test button on the unit acting as on-camera transmitter.  The flashes should fire in sync together. If they don't, check that the on-camera transmitter is properly seated--this is the most likely culprit with misfires.

Answer (score 0):

I use the same flash triggers with 3 yn-560II's. I have all of them set to manual with a trigger on the camera hotshoe and one on a flash. I then set the other 2 flashes only slave mode and this enables me to fire all 3 at the same time.

Hope this helps you out.

All the best,

Leon

Answer (score 0):

You will need your flashes set to slave mode (as was mentiond) and make sure you have your 603's all set to the same channel.